# PDF portfolio navigators

Tags: pdf, embedfile

Using the [embedfile](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) package it is possible to create pdf portfolios/collections with pdfLaTeX. The pdf specification describes the use of custom ["navigators"](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/PDFNAV/PDF+Portfolios+and+Navigators) to create a pleasing interface for the files in the pdf portfolio.

Is it possible to [download](http://blog.practicalpdf.com/portfolios/) or create a custom `.nav` file and embed it directly from LaTeX or with tools other than the full version of Acrobat?

Edit: the description of navigators can be found in the supplement to ISO 32000 [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf#page34).